# How can i upload html file using ninjaform?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to upload .html file using my ninjaform. But i am getting this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYrm8.png)

I have added mime type html using plugin but it's not working. I also used this code

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1 );
function my_myme_types( $mime_types ) {
  $mime_types['svg'] = 'text/html';  
  return $mime_types;
}
```

I am ninjaform and wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide the relevant snippet from your webserver's error log to see why your server returned an HTTP 403 Forbidden in response to the `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=nf_fu_upload` request, in order for us to fully help you.

In the meantime, you may want to read this:

**mod_security Preventing Form Publishing/Submissions**
https://ninjaforms.com/docs/mod_security/

Comment: I am using Godaddy hosting. I already tried this option but nothing. I tried to upload html file using media library and found this error. https://i.ibb.co/z82wc7r/gdaddy.png How can i fix this for all my user ? I know i can fix if i add my IP but i wanna fix this for all my users.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your Ninja Forms plugin?  https://www.zdnet.com/article/ninja-forms-wordpress-bug-exposed-over-a-million-users-to-website-hijacking/

Comment: It was WordPress security plugin which was causing this problem. In future reference, If anyone face similar error. Disable your security plugin.